Error mounting volumes in the docker-compose file
I am a kind new to docker, i just added a docker-compose project in asp.net core solution
in visual studio. I am able to successfully build my solution But when i try
to run the docker-compose project i have this error:
"Error response from daemon: mount denied:
the source path "\\Users\\KACH2321\\AppData\\Roaming/Microsoft/UserSecrets:C:\\Users\\ContainerUser\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\UserSecrets:ro"

Here is what i have tried in my docker-compose.yml file :
services:
  si.ownsa.server:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}siownsaserver
    container_name: si.ownsa.server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: SI.OWNSA.Server\Server\Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - C:/Users/KACH2321/AppData/Roaming/ASP.NET/Https:/ContainerUser/AppData/Roaming/ASP.NET/Https
      - C:/Users/KACH2321/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/ContainerUser/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/UserSecrets

I would appreciate any help

Do those locations exist within the container? Also try using the \ for the windows side
